# How to pass a selected state of the cell in collectionView (Swift)

Tags: swift, collectionview

I have an app with horizontal scroll collectionView and I need to pass the "selected" state to other method, which is saving. So I have custom cell in which I declare an observer:

```
class StoryViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            print("Selected")
        }
    }

}
```

When I scroll, I got this print statements like it should be. But how can I pass this state to my ViewController? I can't access variables inside it. Are there other options to solve this?

I also tried some collectionView delegate's such as `:didSelectItem` and `:didUpdateFocusIn context`
 methods with no luck.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by you tried `didSelectItem` with no luck? If you `print("Selected")` inside `didSelectItem` it doesn't print?

Comment: Yes, it only prints when I click, but I can't afford user to click two times to select. It should be like scrolled->selected and not scrolled->clicked->selected

Comment: It shouldn't require two clicks. Are you sure you didn't accidentally implement `didDeselectItem` instead?

Comment: I think I didn't. `didSelectItemAt`, that's it). I'm using a custom layout for collectionView, maybe that's the issue? Sorry, not my native language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have many ways to do that so one of them:

> You have to create protocols:

```
protocol updateDelegate {
    func update(flag: Bool)
}
```

> And create a delegate object in cell class like that:

```
 var delegate: updateDelegate?
```

> After that, Your  **cellForRowAt:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! DemoTableViewCell

    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

> And cell class methods like that:

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        print("Selected")
        delegate?.update(flag: isSelected)
    }
}
```

And in view controller you have to define update method:

```
func update(flag: Bool) {
    print("fefr")
}
```

> It will work for you

**You can find my full code below:**

> **ViewControllor:**

```
import UIKit

protocol updateDelegate {
    func update(flag: Bool)
}
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, updateDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! DemoTableViewCell

        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
    func update(flag: Bool) {
        print("fefr")
    }
}
```

> **Custom cell class**

```
class DemoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

     var delegate: updateDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            print("Selected")
            delegate?.update(flag: isSelected)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer! But how do I pass the items position as well? Could you please guide me? I tried to use cell's tag but they are not reliable due to cell's reuse

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I need to have to pass information to my business logic from my view logic, I will set up the business logic class as delegate of my view. Then, in the collectionView delegate methods when an interaction happens that needs to pass information to the business logic, the delegate method can be called and data is passed.
For example:

```
//Beginning of your View class
protocol StoryViewCellDelegate {
    //This is the function to be called in your ViewController
    func cellWasSelected()
}

class StoryViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var cellDelegate: StoryViewCellDelegate?
    //... other code you have
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            print("Selected")
            cellDelegate?.cellWasSelected()
        }
    }
}
```

Remember that with this setup, in the ViewController you must implement the protocol StoryViewCellDelegate (usually in an extension of the ViewController class so things don't get messy) and when the cells for the collection view are being created you need to dequeue the cells as StoryViewCell and then set the cell's cellDelegate = self which allows the ViewController to be called as the delegate when the cell is selected.
for more help with how the delegate pattern works, this is a pretty good site to reference:
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/

Hope this helped ^^